# Select DISTINCT records with extra information

Tags: query, ms-access

I have a MS Access database full of customer names and addresses. I want to send out a mailing but only one per address. Therefore if there are 3 different customers at the address I want only one row. Here is the basic query I have so far:

```
Group   Fname   Lname   Address
```

So my first attempt was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.[Address 1]
FROM Customers
```

This works as I wanted and returns only unique addresses. However I also need the group, fname and lname fields. When I add these in I lose the DISTINCT functionality as often customers in the same household will have different Lname and grouping.

Whats the best way to select the data I need but still use DISTINCT on the [Address 1] field.

Comment: And you want one random row from the many in the same address?

Comment: Yes one random row from each address is fine, either that or pick the row with the oldest [Order Date]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM 
      Customers AS c
   INNER JOIN
      ( SELECT [Address 1], MIN([Order Date]) AS min_od
        FROM Customers
        GROUP BY [Address 1]
      ) AS grp
         ON  grp.[Address 1] = c.[Address 1]
         AND grp.min_od = c.[Order Date] ;
```

This may still give you two rows for an address, if you have two rows with the same minimum `[Order Date]` for an address.

Comment: You could use min(FName + LName) instead of min([Order Date]) (hopefully, FName+LName is unique for one address :-) )

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: If uniqueness is required, then he can use `MIN(pk)`